# DropDownChoice wicket get value

Tags: java, apache, wicket, dropdownchoice

so I have my DropDownChoice in Wicket:

```
final DropDownChoice drop_down_status = new DropDownChoice<String>("status", new PropertyModel<String>(this,"selected_status"), STATUS_LIST);

     form.add(drop_down_status);
```

How to get the selected value? I have to get it after another button is pressed and prepare sql statement from it.

drop_down_status.getRawInput()  and drop_down_status.getInput() return null ( at least in my case).

cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wicket updates "selected_status" value "on the fly".

```
new PropertyModel<String>(this,"selected_status")
```

so its enough to get value from Model value :)

Answer (score 2):

Since you are constructing your `DropDownChoice` using a `PropertyModel`, the selection shown during initialization will correspond to the value of your `selected_status` variable.  When the `drop_down_status` is changed, the propety model will update the `selected_status` variable.  So, you should be able to just look at that variable to see to see the current selection in the dropdown.

I have had frustration in the past getting the values from various inputs, but have found the following methods work fairly consistently (pick one):

1. Use a `PropertyModel.  This is the cleanest of the three solutions, explained above.
2. If input was constructed using a `Model` or `PropertyModel` you can call `drop_down_status.getModelObject()` then typecast the returned object back to the correct object type.
3. Use an 'AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior' to trigger an ad-hoc update when the object is modified.

example using AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior:

```
  drop_down_status.add(new AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior("onChange") {
      @Override
      protected void onUpdate(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
          selected_status = (Status) getFormComponent().getConvertedInput();
      }
  }
```

To reitterate what bert said above, models are the core of Wicket (i.e.- MVC=Model,View,Controller) and it helps tremendously to get familiar with their usage.

Answer (score 0):

You pass a model to the DDC.  In your case a property model.  After a successful submit, the value is transferred to the model object 'selected_value'.

If you want to get anywhere with Wicket.  Read up on the usage of models