# Wicket DropDownChoice selected value

Tags: java, wicket, dropdown

I am trying to get the Id of my selected choice on a DropDownChoice but I get an error.. 
I know that when I choose a value I just update the model and not the object (reflection). 
I expected to get all the values of object "User" through getModelObject() but all i get is a NullPointerException.. 
I have tried many things according to tutorials and Wicket 8 documentation but nothing seems to work..

My code is like:

```
  // POJO
    class User {
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    [...]

    }

    // Main.class
    private User selected;

    ChoiceRenderer<User> choiceRenderer = new ChoiceRenderer<User>("id", "name");
    List<User> list = getUsers();

    final DropDownChoice<User> dropdown1 = new DropDownChoice<User>("dropdown",
                    new PropertyModel<User>(this, "selected"), list, choiceRenderer);


    Button btn = new Button("btn") {

                private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

                @Override
                public void onSubmit() {
                    RecrRemoteOperations recr = new RecrRemoteOperations();
                    try {

    // NullPointerException!
    // Integer id = dropdown.getModel().getObject().getId();
      // id: the id of the selected "User" value on dropdown
                        recr.updateCommand(id);

                    } catch (Throwable e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }.setDefaultFormProcessing(false);

    private static List<User> getUsers() {
    List<User> allUsers = new ArrayList<User>();
    [...]
    return list;
    }
```

Comment: Do you have a getter and a setter for `selected`?

Comment: Yeah I tried that but the "selected" object is empty..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in `button.setDefaultFormProcessing(false)`. This tells Wicket to not use the submitted values and to not update the models of the FormComponents, i.e. the DropDownChoice won't have model object and thus won't set `selected`.

`.setDefaultFormProcessing(false)` is usually used for `Cancel` buttons, where you just want to leave the form.

Comment: Indeed the problem was that function .setDefaultFormProcessing(false).. I copied the DropDownChoice from another page and I didnt pay attention.. :)   Thank you martin-g

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but my problem is very similar to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17675833/dropdownchoice-wicket-get-value)
I was told that I don't need to use Ajax but I will try to see if it works